# Canvas over a Canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I want to draw somthing (for exmaple a rect) into a canvas that every loop it moves. and i want to draw a background( for example that the background will be blue), but i want to draw the background only once. so i thought that i would draw the background into one canvas, and i would draw the rect into other canvas and that cnavas's background will be transparent.

is it possible?

how do i set the second canvas to be transparent so that you could see the rect moves(and not replicates it self-becuase you could see the previous rects)

Comment: no, there is only one Canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should draw the background to a Bitmap once. and then draw that bitmap into your canvas every loop iteration.

Comment: can you add an exapmle of how do i do that? i dont know how to set the bitmap's width and height to be the whole canvas if i have to set them before the canvas

Comment: Look a Bitmap.creatBitmap, give it the same width and height as of the view's width and height

Answer (score 0):

You can just have two canvas' stacked on each other using z-index

```
<canvas id="background" style="position: absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:-1"></canvas>
<canvas id="foreground" style="position: absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:0"></canvas>
```

Then in your JavaScript code, just call for each particular canvas separately

```
var backgroundCanvas = document.getElementById("background");
var ctxBackgroundCanvas = backgroundCanvas.getContext("2d");

var foregroundCanvas = document.getElementById("foreground");
var ctxForegroundCanvas = foregroundCanvas .getContext("2d");

function paintBackground() {
//paint background here using ctxBackgroundCanvas
}

function paintForeground() {
//paint foreground here using ctxForegroundCanvas
}
```

At the start of each re-draw of the foreground, don't use fillRect, but instead clearRect, that will make it transparent.